# How can you make permanent changes to a website you own without a server?

Tags: html

Ok, so I have this site which I want to turn into a forum and save user input. LocalStorage isn't an option to me, as I want other users using the site to see what they have posted. I host my websites through Google Drive using a sort of exploit, and I have registered a free domain for it. Problem is, how can I turn it into a forum where it's not just client-side changes? Ok so here's what I do to host: I just have a html file in my google drive, have a plugin that allows for a preview link and take the preview link as the website. This method means I am not capable of having a server, and it's impossible for me to have one. I'm not a really, really advanced programmer, either, so try to keep it simple best you can. I cannot pay for a server slot or a regular website.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that would possibly work is getting a third party message board widget - where the third party handles basically everything for you. Something like [this.](https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/#get_code)

But really, in this day and age you can get hosting for like 5 bucks a month. I recommend you do that.